# Passing non-instantiated classes and interfaces to generic methods

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have inherited hundreds of statements like this:

```
mockKernel.Setup(x => x.Bind<IAddressService>().To<AddressService>())
          .Returns(new BindingConfigurationBuilder<AddressService>(bindingConfiguration, "ServiceName", mockKernel.Object));
```

... as part of tests for hundreds of statements that resemble this:

```
_kernel.Bind<IAddressService>().To<AddressService>().InRequestScope();
```

I'd like to write something like this:

```
private void SetupBindAtoB<TInterface, TImplementation>(TInterface a, TImplementation b)
    where TImplementation : TInterface
{
  mockKernel.Setup(x => x.Bind<TInterface>().To<TImplementation>())
            .Returns(new BindingConfigurationBuilder<TImplementation>(bindingConfiguration, "ServiceName", mockKernel.Object));
}
```

... and then call it like this:

```
SetupBindAtoB(IAddressService, AddressService);
```

But I can't. I have to pass a real object to `SetupBindAtoB`, like this:

```
SetupBindAtoB((IAddressService) null, (AddressService) null);
```

Is it possible to avoid creating real objects to pass to `SetupBindAtoB`?

Comment: How about having SetupBindAtoB create the real instances, if it is not given one? Of course then you would need to specify the exact type for each call. Maybe storing the types in a array of type[] could work? Then it could be down to simple itteration over a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
private void SetupBindAtoB<TInterface, TImplementation>()
    where TImplementation : TInterface
{
  mockKernel.Setup(x => x.Bind<TInterface>().To<TImplementation>())
            .Returns(new BindingConfigurationBuilder<TImplementation>(bindingConfiguration, "ServiceName", mockKernel.Object));
}
```

**Usage**

```
SetupBindAtoB<IAddressService,AddressService>();
```

Comment: Beautiful!  I didn't know that you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

You have two argument parameters that are unused (`TInterface a` and `TImplementation b`). Only the type parameters themselves (`IInterface` and `IImplementation`) are relevant. So just remove the unnecessary parameters:

```
private void SetupBindAtoB<TInterface, TImplementation>()
    where TImplementation : TInterface
{
  mockKernel.Setup(x => x.Bind<TInterface>().To<TImplementation>())
            .Returns(new BindingConfigurationBuilder<TImplementation>(bindingConfiguration, "ServiceName", mockKernel.Object));
}
```

Then you can call the method as follows:

```
SetupBindAtoB<IAddressService, AddressService>();
```

---

In your approach, you are basicially relying on the type inference from the types of the arguments that allows to omit to specify the type parameters themselves. Usually this type inference makes the method invocation shorter. In your case, this just makes it more complicated:

```
SetupBindAtoB((IAddressService) null, (AddressService) null);
```

is actually a "shorthand" for

```
SetupBindAtoB<IAddressService, AddressService>(null, null);
```